# Linode Lish bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, linode, setlocale

Following Linode's guide to [`Copy a Disk Over SSH`](https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/disk-images/copying-a-disk-image-over-ssh/):

```
ssh root@xx.xx.xxx.xx "dd if=/dev/sdX " | dd of=/PathToLocalLocation/server.img
```

Where `xx.xx.xxx.xx` is your server's IP, `sdX` - `X` stands for your drive's assigned letter,  and also you must state the `image`'s name = `server.img`

I ran into this issue (on my local computer):

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

I conducted a long search with many results which none of worked for `Lish` nor were they a complete solution.

I couldn't set `locales` on the `Lish command line` no matter what I did....
All the answers out there are regarding `command-line` on local or servers, not `rescue-mode`....
Ideas?

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C` which should work everywhere. It effectively disables any Unicode support and various other locale-dependent behaviors but time travel back to the previous millennium is probably acceptable for this particular use case.

Comment: doesn't work....got the same error `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

Comment: Then the cange didn't take. You need to make sure the variable is set and exported in the shell where you run the command. It's not clear from your question whether the error is local or remote, but `ssh` is unsuallytconfigurel to "transport" your local locale settings to the remote, too.

Comment: Then issue is with remote as `Lish` mounts a rescue partition `Finnix` based and does not have locales installed, hence sending `LC_ALL=C` via `ssh` would not help. This fix, coming from `linode` guide resolves this issue

Answer (score 49):

Trial & error with different answers, I came up with this solution (on `Lish` while server is in `rescue-mode`):

```
echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Last command resulted in the following error:

`locale-gen: command not found`

Here's what you need to do (still on `Lish`):

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update
apt-get install locales
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete
```

You're good to go...copy your server's disk over to your local machine.

Comment: For my case I need to execute "sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: On Debian 11, try it as root.

Comment: I'm also using Debian. But it seemed that the `locale -a` command was returning en_US with lower caps utf-8 (so NOT UTF-8 but utf-8).  I changed that manually in  /etc/locale.conf. And also exported: `export LC_ALL="en_US.utf-8"`. Now finally `dpkg-reconfigure locales` succeeds.

Comment: sudo echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.confbash: /etc/environment: Permission denied

Answer (score 40):

for anyone coming across this post on Debian11 - but should also work on earlier versions - and on similar flavours like Ubuntu.  The error indicates that your locales are not generated.

To resolve:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Select the desired locales - or all of them. Next you will be asked if you wish to set a default system locale.  Select the desired option - for example  en_US.UTF-8 and use TAB to go to OK and press enter.

All done.

Comment: worked well on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: For some reason, raspberry pi OS lite installation results in the same error; successfully fixed as suggested here (no addition to /etc/ files)

Comment: A combination of this and @Jadeye's answer worked well with OpenMediaVault 6.0.24 (based on Debian 11)

Comment: just work on WSL2 windows 

Answer (score 6):

To fix the warning follow the following steps:

Open the environment file in the etc folder with your preferred editor.

```
vi /etc/environment
```

Press `i` key to enter edit mode, add the following lines to the file.

```
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

Pressing Esc key and type `:wq` to "write/save" the file and exit the editor.
Run `source /etc/environment`

The warning is now fixed and should be gone from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not have a package installed. This package may be missing in some Docker containers. At least, this was an issue that I encountered.

```
glibc-langpack-en
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but you could simply be missing the en_US.UTF-8 locale on your local computer, you can try generating it with `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` (on your local computer).

Comment: This was exactly the case in my chrooted environment. `locale -a` showed only C and POSIX. I have uncommented `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` in _/etc/locale.gen_ and run `locale-gen`. Now `locale -a` shows en_US.utf8 as well. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I got this after installing bash_it scripts locally. I tried editing the /etc/environment file first but that didn't work. This was the 2nd thing I tried and it worked for me.